# How to match a user's uid stored in document field inside Firebase security rule for Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to check for the UID stored in the document field of a document (of the parent collection named ***premiumID***) against the UID of the user requesting the data. In simpler words, I want the user to only access the document which contains his UID.

Here's what I have done until now

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    match /premiumID/{docId} {

      function userData() {
        return resource.data.uid
      }

      allow update: if userData() == request.auth.uid;
      allow delete: if userData() == request.auth.uid;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow read: if userData() == request.auth.uid;
    }    
  }
}
```

Here's what my DB looks like-

[image]

Here's how I am testing it. This gives me ***read and write denied***.

[image]

Comment: Please don't share links to code on Stack Overflow.  Copy the code into the question itself.

Comment: Your rule states a  collection name of exactly "pID", but your database is apparently showing something different which is blurred out.  If there's not an exact match, it's not going to work.

Comment: @DougStevenson I intentionally blurred out the premiumID field, but I guess I forgot to do it in the other picture. I checked and copy pasted the path and the collection name or document ID everywhere, so I don't make a typo.

Comment: Could you try using the rules [simulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator), so we can see what happens if you run locally, cause everything appears to be in order indeed and your rules should be working.

Answer (score 2):

The rule `allow write: if request.auth.uid == request.resource.data.uid;` checks if user authentication is the same as the field `uid` that the document contains. 
But as said in the comments of your question your collection name doesn't match the rule that you are using.

Check this [site](https://fireship.io/snippets/firestore-rules-recipes/) it contains very useful information about firebase rules. It really helped me when I started using firebase rules for more complicated rules.

Comment: As I added in the comments, I intentionally changed the collection name to pID, but it's premiumID everywhere. As far as Fireship goes, I referenced it to write these rules in the first place. My question is that I can't find a way to read the document fields from the request.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you want to match a document you have to use `{document}` instead of `{docId}`. I also had similar problem and changing to `{document}` solved it.

```
match /pID/{document}
```

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, it is just a wildcard variable and what you call it doesn't matter.

Comment: The variable name between the `{}` can be anything. During a `list` query, the value of the variable is `*` otherwise it's the id of the document (for a `get` query).